# How can I add displaying delay to menu items with sub-menu?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, delay

In order to improve user experience, I want to add delay in displaying one of menu items on my website that has a lot of sub-menu items. My website is in Farsi, This menu Item is called "خدمات ما" and you can visit my website from [here](https://www.prjmarket.com).[Top Menu picture of my website with the above mentioned menu item being marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMAPF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You might doi it with css delay property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Hope this helps